# Error abriendo una base de datos SQLite

Tags: java, android

aqui tengo este código:

```
encuestadoSQLiteHelper encuestado = new encuestadoSQLiteHelper(this, "DBEncuestado", null, 1);
                        final SQLiteDatabase db = encuestado.getWritableDatabase();
                        String nombre = "Pablo";
                        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Encuestado (nombre) " +
                                "VALUES (" + nombre +"')");
```

En la línea: `(this, "DBEncuestado", null, 1);` me aparece error. No sé que pasa, ayuda!

Comment: Una recomendación, trata de usar mayúsculas en nombres de clases y minúsculas en variables y campos. Eso es una convención común y evita confusiónes en leer tu código. :) (Eje. `EncuestadoSWLiteHelper`)

Answer (score 1):

Te falta la primera comilla simple en tu codigo :

Tu codigo :

```
String nombre = "Pablo";
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Encuestado (nombre) " +
"VALUES (" + nombre +"')");
```

Debe quedar :

```
String nombre = "Pablo";
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Encuestado (nombre) " +
"VALUES ('" + nombre +"')");
```

Comment: Gracias bro!!! me savaste la vida, pero ahora mi pregunta es: ¿Por qué en Android/data/ no está el paquete java de mi aplicación donde debería estar la base de datos? Gracias! No encuentro el paquete `com.example.pablo.myapplication;`